# How to view Allure report when the tests are running?

Tags: java, python, allure

How to view Allure report when the tests are running ?
Right now, I have the config/setup to generate allure report once the tests is completed .
I'm trying to view the allure report when the test execution is in progress. Kindly help me out with options . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is possible at all. For example when you run tests with maven surefire will generate files upon test phase is finished. Allure will generate report based on that files.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in Allure Server only. You can read and watch more on their updated [website](https://qameta.io/). Generally speaking, Allure Server is more than just a report. It allows you to manage test cases (both manual and automated), provides integration with CI/CD, Jira, etc. You can run test suites from within web UI and see the results dynamically. It's worth saying Allure Server is not free though.